# How to group values in an array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

How do I make it so every value in `$values` is connected to every value gotten from the row, `$row[1]`?

```
$values = implode(',', $valueIDArray);
$query = "SELECT * FROM venue_booking
WHERE venue_id IN ($values)";

$result1 =& $db->query($query);
if (PEAR::isError($query)) {
    die($result->getMessage());
}

while($row = $result1 -> fetchrow()){
    $dateValues[] = $row[1];
}
```

I want to make a table like this

```
 ID         DATE
--------- ----------
 7         04/12/13
 7         03/12/13
 7         04/11/13
 7         22/10/13
 4         05/12/12
 5         05/02/12
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the table structure and what you would like the result to look like?

Answer (score 0):

MySQLI or PDO would be much better than PEAR, but if you must you would be much better off using `DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC` or whatver for that PEAR class, but assuming `venue_id` is `$row[0]` then something like:

```
while($row = $result1 -> fetchrow()){
    $dateValues[] = array($row[0], $row[1]);
}
```